# PyQt4 - add a text edit area animation example

Tags: python, animation, resize, pyqt4

I have realized a python simple application, without any animation on it.
Now I want to add a simple animation, triggered by a signal (a button click for example), which on trigger enlarges the width of the windows and shows a new text area with some text in it.

Honestly, I am quite new to python/pyqt4, and I do not know much about the animation framework.

I tried to add this to my class code, for example in a method called clicking on the about menu :) :

```
  self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self, "size")
  self.anim.setDuration(2500)
  self.anim.setStartValue(QSize(self.width(), self.height()))
  self.anim.setEndValue(QSize(self.width()+100, self.height()))
  self.anim.start()
```

and this enlarge my window as I want.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to insert a new text area, avoiding the widgets already present to fill the new space (actually, when the window enlarge, the widgets use
all the spaces, thus enlarging themselves)

Could someone help me knowing how to add the text area appearance animation?

Any help is appreciated...really...

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to animate the `maximumWidth` property on both the window and the text-edit.

The main difficulty is doing it in a way that plays nicely with standard layouts whilst also allowing resizing of the window. Avoiding flicker during the animation is also quite tricky.

The following demo is almost there (the animation is slightly jerky at the beginning and end):

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        self._offset = 200
        self._closed = False
        self._maxwidth = self.maximumWidth()
        self.widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.listbox = QtGui.QListWidget(self.widget)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Slide', self.widget)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        self.editor = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        self.editor.setMaximumWidth(self._offset)
        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        vbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        vbox.addWidget(self.listbox)
        vbox.addWidget(self.button)
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.editor)
        layout.setSizeConstraint(QtGui.QLayout.SetMinAndMaxSize)
        self.animator = QtCore.QParallelAnimationGroup(self)
        for item in (self, self.editor):
            animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(item, 'maximumWidth')
            animation.setDuration(800)
            animation.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.OutCubic)
            self.animator.addAnimation(animation)
        self.animator.finished.connect(self.handleFinished)

    def handleButton(self):
        for index in range(self.animator.animationCount()):
            animation = self.animator.animationAt(index)
            width = animation.targetObject().width()
            animation.setStartValue(width)
            if self._closed:
                self.editor.show()
                animation.setEndValue(width + self._offset)
            else:
                animation.setEndValue(width - self._offset)
        self._closed = not self._closed
        self.widget.setMinimumSize(self.widget.size())
        self.layout().setSizeConstraint(QtGui.QLayout.SetFixedSize)
        self.animator.start()

    def handleFinished(self):
        if self._closed:
            self.editor.hide()
        self.layout().setSizeConstraint(QtGui.QLayout.SetMinAndMaxSize)
        self.widget.setMinimumSize(0, 0)
        self.setMaximumWidth(self._maxwidth)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.move(500, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```